# apparmor wildcard profile with globbing

Tags: ubuntu, wildcards, apparmor

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with apparmor 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.7. I often need to comment on software of dubious quality. I want to employ apparmor to guard my system from harm.

I created an apparmor wildcard profile like this:

```
/home/username/testing/** {
  somerules
}
```

Unfortunately, this profile has no effect. It works as expected as soon as I put the exact path without a wildcard:

```
/home/username/testing/client42/executable {
  somerules
}
```

On the manpage, it looks like globbing is supported for profiles:

```
PROFILE = ( PROFILE HEAD ) [ ATTACHMENT SPECIFICATION ] [ PROFILE FLAG CONDS ] '{' ( RULES )* '}'
PROFILE HEAD = [ 'profile' ] FILEGLOB | 'profile' PROFILE NAME
```

[This wiki article](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/AppArmor_Core_Policy_Reference#Profile_names_with_globbing_.28AppArmor_2.4_and_later.29) says so, too. There even is a user [reporting success](https://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/wildcard-based-apparmor-profiles.383413/).

What am I missing?
Do wildcards in profiles need to be explicitly enabled in a configuration file?
Is globbing disabled in the Ubuntu build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tinkering around with this problem today, I found the wildcard profile working as expected after a reboot. It looks like setting the profile to enforce mode with `aa-enforce /etc/apparmor.d/<profile>` or reloading the profile with `apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/<profile>` as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor#Reload_one_profile) and [here](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/AppArmor_Failures#Updating_the_policy) is not sufficient for wildcard profiles. I am unsure if reloading the service via `systemctl reload apparmor` is sufficient to activate the wildcard profile, but a system restart definitely is.